# External URLs don't open in webview

Tags: reactjs, webview, electron, vite, electron-react

i'm making electron app using npm `create electron-vite` (typescript, react).
To load url, I'm using webview. It works fine, but external urls don't open, new-window and setWindowOpenHandler just not called.

```js
app.on("web-contents-created", (e, contents) => {
  // web-contents-created function work's fun, contents is real object.
  if (contents.getType() == "webview") {
    // Listen for any new window events
    contents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }: HandlerDetails) => {
      console.log("Click!");
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(url);
      shell.openExternal(url);
      return { action: "deny" };
    });
  }
}
```

I also tried to add events from main.jsx, still doesn't work.